# Homomorphic Encryption Arithmetic Psuedo

Tags: algorithm, math, encryption, pseudocode

I am looking to do arithmetic operations on encrypted values that will decrypt to be the result of the value decrypted. Does anyone know of any code examples of this in use? Usage of the equation would be nice as well.The psuedo from the below link is rather obscure.

[Homomorphic Multiplication/Addition](https://nvotes.com/multiplicative-vs-additive-homomorphic-elgamal/)

**So ideally given v1 and v2**

v1 = 5;
v2 = 4;

Decrypt(v1Encrypted + v2Encrypted) = 9;

Comment: That depends on the encryption method. Some allow these operations (e.g. RSA), some don't. This question might fit better on [crypto.se], [cs.se], or [math.se].

Comment: Thanks for the info. I definitely need it to work with RSA

Answer (score 0):

You can do exactly that with the homomorphic encryption library [Pyfhel](https://pypi.org/project/Pyfhel/) in Python. Just install it using `pip install Pyfhel` and create a simple demo:

```
from Pyfhel import Pyfhel, PyCtxt

he = Pyfhel()        # Object in charge of all homomorphic operations
he.contextGen(10000) # Choose the maximum size of your integers
he.keyGen(10000)     # Generate your private/public key pair

# Now to the encryption/operation/decryption
v1 = 5
v2 = 4

p1 = he.encrypt(v1)
p2 = he.encrypt(v2)

p3 = p1 + p2

he.decrypt(p3)
#> 9
```

Comment: Up-to-date code can be found in [Demo_1_HelloWorld.py](https://github.com/ibarrond/Pyfhel/blob/master/examples/Demo_1_HelloWorld.py)

Answer (score 0):

You may consider to use LightPHE which wraps many additively and multiplicatively homomorphic encryption algorithms

```py
# !pip install lightphe
from lightphe import LightPHE

# build an additively homomorphic cryptosystem
cs = LightPHE(algorithm_name = "EllipticCurve-ElGamal")

# define plaintexts
m1 = 17
m2 = 23

# calculate ciphertexts
c1 = cs.encrypt(m1)
c2 = cs.encrypt(m2)

# homomorphic addition - private key is not required!
c3 = c1 + c2

# proof of work
assert cs.decrypt(c3) == m1 + m2
```

Similarly, if you can adopt a multiplicatively homomorphic encryption algorithm as

```py
from lightphe import LightPHE

# build an additively homomorphic cryptosystem
cs = LightPHE(algorithm_name = "ElGamal")

# define plaintexts
m1 = 17
m2 = 23

# calculate ciphertexts
c1 = cs.encrypt(m1)
c2 = cs.encrypt(m2)

# homomorphic multiplication - private key is not required!
c3 = c1 * c2

# proof of work
assert cs.decrypt(c3) == m1 * m2
```

Long story short, multiplicatively homomorphic algorithms are RSA, ElGamal; additively homomorphic algorithms are Exponential-ElGamal, EllipticCurve-ElGamal, Paillier, Damgard-Jurik, Benaloh, Naccache-Stern and Okamoto-Uchiyama; and algorithm that homomorphic with respect to the XOR is Goldwasser-Micali.